# Transfer specific tables using heroku pg:transfer

Tags: heroku

With the taps gem it was possible to do:

```
heroku db:pull -f '^(?!requests).*' --app AppName --confirm AppName"
```

which would transfer the schema and all tables and indexes except for those of the `requests` table would be left in the production database.

Is there any option to do this yet with pg:transfer?  I can't see one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the full `pg_dump` command on your local computer against your remote heroku postgres database. `pg_dump` has several options, including selectively dumping tables.

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html for the complete information on `pg_dump`